# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a few problems and I have been stuck on this one for quite some time. I cannot figure out how to get past the AttributeError.

Within the function that is causing the problem, I have another function called safeOpen, which opens files, but won't give an error if there isn't a file with that specific name.

```
def safeOpen(fileName):
try:
    infile = open(fileName)
    print('Opened')
except:
    print('None')
```

In my main function, avgSpd, I have the user input the file name and it gets opened with safeOpen. However, when the program goes to read the file it gives me the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`.
I have tested safeOpen to see if that is the problem, but testing safeOpen alone shows that safeOpen is working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def avgSpd():
    fileName = input('Enter the file name: ')
    infile = safeOpen(fileName)
    content = infile.read()
```

Comment: `infile = safeOpen(fileName)` assigns the value returned by the function call to `infile`, right? Now the question is: what does `safeOpen(fileName)` _return_?

Comment: `safeOpen` doesn't return `infile` (or anything at all), so when you do `infile = safeOpen()`, you're replacing the value of `infile` with `None`.

Comment: Also: Don't catch *all* errors, but only the ones you expect to happen. You could use `except Exception as e: print(e)` to log errors you didn't expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `safeOpen` doesn't have a return statement, so the `infile` variable in the `avgSpd` function is set to None.

try:

```
def safeOpen(fileName):
    try:
        infile = open(fileName)
        print('Opened')
        return infile
    except:
        print('None')
        return None
```

It's worth noting that it's best to use context managers (that is, the `with' statement) to make sure that the file is safely opened. You could also check using the os.path.exists() function if your file exists rather than using try/except, too.

Something like:

```
import os

def safeOpen(fileName):
     if os.path.exists(fileName):
         with open(fileName) as f:
              content = f.read()
     else:
         content = None
     
     return content

def avgSpd():
    fileName = input('Enter the file name: ')
    content = safeOpen(fileName)
    if content is not None:
        do_more_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not returned the `infile` variable in inner function. corrected version will be:

```py
def safeOpen(fileName):
    try:
        infile = open(fileName)
        print('Opened')
    except:
        print('None')
    return infile


def avgSpd():
    fileName = input('Enter the file name: ')
    infile = safeOpen(fileName)
    content = infile.read()
    return content
```